# Every bounded, infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a cluster point.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am struggling to move forward with this proof...

I have been given that for some $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a cluster point of the set $A$ if $A$ $\cap$ $(a-r, a+r)$ contains infinitely many points for all $r>0$.

From looking into cluster points, it does seem that this is an alternative form of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Here's what I have attempted so far (very similar to proof of BWT using nested interval property):

Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be bounded by $M$, and consider the interval $[-M, M]$.

We can split this interval in half: $[-M, M]=[-M, 0] \cup [0, M]$.

As we are dealing with an infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we must have infinitely many terms of $E$ in one of these two sub-intervals.

Without loss of generality, let us assume that such an interval is $[0,M]$, and denote this $I_1$. Now we take some $x_1$ from $A$ such that $x_1 \in I_1$.

We then continue again to find a sequence of closed, bounded, nested intervals $(I_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where some $x_n \in I_n$.

From here I am very unsure where to go. I understand that the intersection of these intervals is nonempty, but I don't know how to link this to the proof in question.

Any help massively appreciated. I understood the BWT proof well, but I think the inclusion of cluster points has thrown me as I do not have much intuitive understanding of what they are.

Comment: The length of your interval is $2M/2^n$ and each interval contains infinitely many points. Thus, if you pick $a\in \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} I_n$, then for every small ball around $a$ you have infinitely msny elements from $A$. This is because for every fixed $r>0$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ sufficiently large such that $I_N \subseteq (a-r, a+r)$.

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense now. Thank you!! Intuitively this makes sense. I must ask though, where in the proof would the size of each subinterval be required? I know if the lengths of the nested intervals tends to 0 (as the expression you have provided does), then there is only one element of the intersection. But the question states there is AT LEAST one cluster point. Where would the others come from if there are more than 1?

Comment: The size is needed to conclude that there exists some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $I_n \subseteq (a-r, a+r)$. As the interval has length $2M/2^n$ and contains $a$, we have $I_N\subseteq (a-2M/2^n, a+ 2M/2^n)$ and for $n$ sufficiently large we have $r>2M/2^n$ which allows us to conclude $I_n \subseteq (a-2M/2^n, a+ 2M/2^n) \subseteq (a-r, a+r)$.